# Vacuum Pump Oil Backflow Prevention Mechanisms

Tags: vacuum-pumps

How do rotary vane vacuum pumps that prevent oil backflow do so? It does not seem like they use check valves since check valves require a differential pressure drop to be effective and the rotary vacuum pumps are capable of pumping a vacuum below what a check valve will work with.

For example, the check valve on McMaster-Carr with the lowest operating pressure has it listed at 0.07psi which is 3600 microns. But these pumps can pull as low as a few tens of microns.

Nor does it seem like they use a solenoid activated valve.

Comment: do you not close a valve after you draw a vacuum?

Comment: @TigerGuy I do but oil still makes it back out into the hose over time and repeated uses somehow, but those are pumps without backflow prevention. I am asking about pumps advertised as having backflow prevention.